# What is the role of epoch in this Geron's code?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I am reading Hands-On ML 2nd Edition. In page 142 there is the following code as an example of Early Stopping:

```
np.random.seed(42)
m = 100
X = 6 * np.random.rand(m, 1) - 3
y = 2 + X + 0.5 * X**2 + np.random.randn(m, 1)

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X[:50], y[:50].ravel(), test_size=0.5, random_state=10)
from copy import deepcopy

poly_scaler = Pipeline([
        ("poly_features", PolynomialFeatures(degree=90, include_bias=False)),
        ("std_scaler", StandardScaler())
    ])

X_train_poly_scaled = poly_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_val_poly_scaled = poly_scaler.transform(X_val)

sgd_reg = SGDRegressor(max_iter=1, tol=-np.infty, warm_start=True,
                       penalty=None, learning_rate="constant", eta0=0.0005, random_state=42)

minimum_val_error = float("inf")
best_epoch = None
best_model = None
for epoch in range(1000):
    sgd_reg.fit(X_train_poly_scaled, y_train) 
    y_val_predict = sgd_reg.predict(X_val_poly_scaled)
    val_error = mean_squared_error(y_val, y_val_predict)
    if val_error < minimum_val_error:
        minimum_val_error = val_error
        best_epoch = epoch
        best_model = deepcopy(sgd_reg)
```

In the lines

```
        sgd_reg.fit(X_train_poly_scaled, y_train)  
        y_val_predict = sgd_reg.predict(X_val_poly_scaled)
        val_error = mean_squared_error(y_val, y_val_predict)
```

I cannot see the role of epoch. What is updating?

Answer (score 1):

In the code, `epoch` is a sequence of ints from 0 to 999 that is iterated over in the for loop.

What's being updated on each iteration? At `sgd_reg.fit(X_train_poly_scaled, y_train)` the `SGDRegressor` is being fit on the training data.

The [SGDRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html) args specify `max_iter=1`, so each epoch represents a single pass over the training data and the model `sgd_reg` is updated each time.

Comment: Just to add, if error is less than previous minimum error, best model get updated to new one.